# VScode Mocha Test Explorer: Worker Error: No test files found: {}

Tags: visual-studio-code, mocha.js, test-explorer

Trying to load/run tests from VScode with Mocha Test Explorer, but it fails with a mocha error while loading my tests.

I added this to `settings.json`

```
    "mochaExplorer.mochaPath": "/Users/daviddeasy/.nvm/versions/node/v18.11.0/bin/mocha",
    "mochaExplorer.files": "test/unit/test/*.js",
```

and Test Explorer can see the test file ok, but then the mocha worker fails.

```
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.171] [INFO] Loading test files of /Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.172] [DEBUG] Using working directory: /Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.195] [DEBUG] Using nodePath: /Users/daviddeasy/.nvm/versions/node/v18.11.0/bin/node
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.302] [DEBUG] Using Mocha options: {"ui":"bdd","timeout":2000,"retries":0,"requires":[],"delay":false,"fullTrace":false,"exit":false,"asyncOnly":false,"parallel":false}
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.303] [DEBUG] Looking for test files ["test/unit/test/*.js"] in /Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.303] [DEBUG] Found test files ["/Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/test/unit/test/analyticsPushTests.js","/Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/test/unit/test/endpointTests.js","/Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/test/unit/test/propertySubstitution.js","/Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/test/unit/test/testFinalTaskCleanup.js"]
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.303] [DEBUG] Using environment variables from config: {}
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.304] [DEBUG] Spawning /Users/daviddeasy/.vscode/extensions/hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter-2.14.1/out/worker/bundle.js with IPC options {}
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.341] [INFO] Worker: Using the mocha package at /Users/daviddeasy/.nvm/versions/node/v18.11.0/bin/mocha
[2023-12-06 17:49:59.410] [ERROR] Worker (stderr): [31mError: No test files found: "{}"[39m

[2023-12-06 17:49:59.418] [INFO] Worker finished with code 1 and signal null
```

I expected Test Explorer to provide the test info to mocha but maybe I need to configure the same test info for both Test Explorer and mocha?

I can run tests find from command line, e.g.

```
mocha mocha test/unit/test
```

Answer (score 0):

Working ok after removing the 2 'mochaExplorer' lines I added to settings.json and putting the creating a `.mocharc.json` file with the test files spec

```
{
  "spec": ["test/unit/test/*.js"],
  "recursive": true
}
```

I think the problem was probably the `mochaExplorer.mochaPath` entry that I added to settings.json to try to get around an earlier problem.

```
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.635] [INFO] Loading test files of /Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.636] [DEBUG] Using working directory: /Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.659] [DEBUG] Using nodePath: /Users/daviddeasy/.nvm/versions/node/v18.11.0/bin/node
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.755] [DEBUG] Using Mocha options: {"ui":"bdd","timeout":2000,"retries":0,"requires":[],"delay":false,"fullTrace":false,"exit":false,"asyncOnly":false,"parallel":false}
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.755] [DEBUG] Looking for test files ["test/unit/test/*.js"] in /Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.755] [DEBUG] Found test files ["/Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/test/unit/test/analyticsPushTests.js","/Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/test/unit/test/endpointTests.js","/Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/test/unit/test/propertySubstitution.js","/Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/test/unit/test/testFinalTaskCleanup.js"]
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.755] [DEBUG] Using environment variables from config: {}
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.755] [DEBUG] Spawning /Users/daviddeasy/.vscode/extensions/hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter-2.14.1/out/worker/bundle.js with IPC options {}
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.796] [INFO] Worker: Using the mocha package at /Users/daviddeasy/dev/velox/apim/node_modules/mocha
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.821] [INFO] Worker: Patching Mocha
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.821] [INFO] Worker: Loading files
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.821] [INFO] Worker: Trying to use Mocha's experimental ESM module loader
[2023-12-06 20:13:52.822] [INFO] Worker: Patching describe
<etc>
```